# Ruby merge n Hash Elements and take middle key

Tags: ruby, hash, merge

I have an hash with following structur:

```
{
  timestamp1 => { attr1 => 1, attri2 => 2, attr3 => 3},
  timestamp2 => { attr1 => 1, attri2 => 2, attr3 => 3},
  timestamp3 => { attr1 => 1, attri2 => 2, attr3 => 3},
  ...
}
```

What I do is to sum n elements together, and take the middle timestamp.
So for example in this case, if would merge 3 days together i would like this result:

```
{
  timestamp2 => {attr1 => 3. attr2 => 6, attr3 => 9}
  timestamp5 => ... # Here the next summed values
  ...
}
```

i do this now allready and it is working, but the code isn't exactly nice, it just merges the first and last element until only the middle one is left:

```
hash.each_slice(n) do |part|
  iterator = 0

  while(part.length > 1) do
   hash_a = part.first.last
   hash_b = part.last.last

   new_values = hash_a.merge(hash_b){ | key, oldval, newval| (newval + oldval)

   if iteration % 2 == 0
     part[0][1] = new_values
     part.delete_at(part.count-1)
   else 
     part.delete_at(0)
     part[part.count-1][1] = new_values
   end
   iteration += 1
 end
```

Note: I know this code is not beautiful, but you don't have to correct this, it is just an example, not my actual code.

Now what I would like to know. Is there a better way to achieve this with some reduces, selects, group_by's or merges. It would be great if I could get rid of the while loop.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you given an example it's helpful to assign a variable to each input (e.g., `h = { timestamp1 =>...`). That way, readers can refer to the variable (e.g., `h`), without having to define it. Secondly, no `...`. please. Make the example complete and show the desired result, so those offering solutions can demonstrate their code produces that result. Make the example as short as possible, but still cover the bases.

Comment: What you refer to as an array is a hash. Your hash's keys appear to be unstated local variables or methods. You need to show the code for those variables or methods, or make the keys all literals (e.g., symbols or strings). In any event, the hash must be a valid Ruby object. You also need to tell us what you want when the size of the hash is not a multiple of the group size, and which key to use when the number of elements per group is even. If the group has four elements, for example, should we use the key for the second or third element of the group?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes yes it is a hash, sorry that was typing before thinking. But for the rest, as i said, this is example code, not what i actually do, or have done. I am completly aware, that these are not valid hash keys. And like I said, i do not need to have this code corrected. Also for the answer it doesn't matter what you do with a even sized hash, because you all are not here to write my code, just to help me on the right way ;-) But thank you anyway for looking at my case!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
N = 3

hash.each_slice(N).map do |part|
  [part[part.size / 2].first, part.each_with_object({}) do |(_, v), acc|
    acc.merge!(v) { |_, v1, v2| v1 + v2 }
  end]
end.to_h
```

Comment: very very interesting, thank you a lot for the answer. Unfortunaly i can see no change in my hash. But i think it isn't a problem with your method, but with my code. I will try it some more, and accept your answer once i am able to run it. Anyway I already learned some new things from reading it. Thank you!

Comment: The code above does not modify the hash inplace. That was not intended at all. It produces a new hash instance. You might reassign your original variable, or `clear!.merge!` to modify it inplace afterwards.

Comment: no no, it is absolutly fine, I understood that in the meantime ;-). I found all my errors in the data, and your answer is spot on what i searched ! Only point to improve (or at least in my case) -> I replaced part[N/2] with part[part.count/2] to make it run througth incomplete groups. (I work with date keys, and slice them at interval, and not every set is complete).

Comment: Fixed an issue/updated an answer with incomplete groups (`part.size`.)

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def group(h,n)
  h.each_slice(n).with_object({}) do |a,g|
    key = a[(a.size-1)/2].first
    a.each {|k,f| g.update(key=>f) {|_,oh,nh| oh.merge(nh) {|_,ov,nv| ov+nv}}}
  end
end
```

This does not mutate `h`.

**Example**

To demonstrate the code I will use a hash containing literals for keys.

```
h = {
  :timestamp1 => { :attr1 => 1, :attri2 => 2, :attr3 => 3},
  :timestamp2 => { :attr1 => 1, :attri2 => 2, :attr3 => 3},
  :timestamp3 => { :attr1 => 1, :attri2 => 2, :attr3 => 3},
  :timestamp4 => { :attr1 => 4, :attri2 => 5, :attr3 => 6},
  :timestamp5 => { :attr1 => 4, :attri2 => 5, :attr3 => 6},
  :timestamp6 => { :attr1 => 4, :attri2 => 5, :attr3 => 6},
}

group(h,1) == h
  #=> true 
group(h,2)
  #=> {:timestamp1=>{:attr1=>2,  :attri2=>4,  :attr3=>6},
  #    :timestamp3=>{:attr1=>5,  :attri2=>7,  :attr3=>9},
  #    :timestamp5=>{:attr1=>8,  :attri2=>10, :attr3=>12}} 
group(h,3)
  #=> {:timestamp2=>{:attr1=>3,  :attri2=>6,  :attr3=>9},
  #    :timestamp5=>{:attr1=>12, :attri2=>15, :attr3=>18}} 
group(h,4)
  #=> {:timestamp2=>{:attr1=>7,  :attri2=>11, :attr3=>15},
  #    :timestamp5=>{:attr1=>8,  :attri2=>10, :attr3=>12}} 
group(h,5)
  #=> {:timestamp3=>{:attr1=>11, :attri2=>16, :attr3=>21},
  #    :timestamp6=>{:attr1=>4,  :attri2=>5,  :attr3=>6}} 
group(h,6)
  #=> {:timestamp4=>{:attr1=>15, :attri2=>21, :attr3=>27}}
```

**Explanation**

I have used the forms of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash.merge!`) and [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employ a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the docs for explanations of the block variables `_` (the common key<sup>1</sup>), `oh` ("old hash"), `nh` ("new hash"), `ov` ("old value") and `nv` ("new value").

The steps are as follows.

```
n = 3
enum0 = h.each_slice(n)
  #=> #<Enumerator: {:timestamp1=>{:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3},
  #                  :timestamp2=>{:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3},
  #                  ...
  #                  :timestamp6=>{:attr1=>4, :attri2=>5, :attr3=>6}}
  #     :each_slice(3)> 
enum1 = enum0.with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator:
  #     #<Enumerator: {:timestamp1=>{:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3},
  #                    :timestamp2=>{:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3},
  #                    ...
  #                    :timestamp6=>{:attr1=>4, :attri2=>5, :attr3=>6}}
  #     :each_slice(3)>:with_object({})>
```

We can examine the (two) elements that will be generated by `enum1` and passed to the block by converting `enum1` to an array.

```
enum1.to_a
  #=> [
  #     [
  #       [
  #         [:timestamp1, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #         [:timestamp2, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #         [:timestamp3, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}]],
  #         {}
  #       ],
  #     [
  #       [
  #         [:timestamp4, {:attr1=>4, :attri2=>5, :attr3=>6}],
  #         [:timestamp5, {:attr1=>4, :attri2=>5, :attr3=>6}],
  #         [:timestamp6, {:attr1=>4, :attri2=>5, :attr3=>6}]],
  #         {}
  #       ]
  #     ]
```

The empty arrays are represented by the block variable `g`. The will be built and returned by the method. The first element generated by `enum1` is passed to the block and the two block variables are assigned, using *parallel assignment*.

```
a,g = enum1.next
  #=> [
  #     [
  #       [:timestamp1, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #       [:timestamp2, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #       [:timestamp3, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}]
  #     ]
  #     {}
  #   ]
a #=> [
  #     [:timestamp1, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #     [:timestamp2, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #     [:timestamp3, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}]
  #   ] 
g #=> {}
```

The block calculation can now be performed.

```
key = a[(a.size-1)/2].first
  #=> a[2].first
  #=> [:timestamp2, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}].first 
  #=> :timestamp2 
enum2 = a.each
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[:timestamp1, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #                  [:timestamp2, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #                  [:timestamp3, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}]]
  #     :each> 
enum2.to_a # for display purposes only
  #=> [[:timestamp1, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #    [:timestamp2, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}],
  #    [:timestamp3, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}]] 
k,f = enum2.next
  #=> [:timestamp1, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}] 
k #=> :timestamp1 
f #=> {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3} 
g.update(key=>f) {|_,oh,nh|
  oh.merge(nh) {|_,ov,nv| g.update(key=>f) {|_,oh,nh| oh.merge(nh) {|_,ov,nv| ov+nv}}}}
  #=> g.update(:timestamp2=>{:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3} ) {|_,oh,nh|
  #     oh.merge(nh) {|_,ov,nv| ov+nv}}}}
  #=> {:timestamp2=>{:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}}
```

Then

```
k,f = enum2.next
  #=> [:timestamp2, {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3}] 
k #=> :timestamp2 
f #=> {:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3} 
g.update(key=>f) {|_,oh,nh| oh.merge(nh) {|_,ov,nv| ov+nv}}
  # g.update(:timestamp2=>{:attr1=>1, :attri2=>2, :attr3=>3} {|_,oh,nh|
  #   oh.merge(nh) {|_,ov,nv| ov+nv}}
  #=> {:timestamp2=>{:attr1=>2, :attri2=>4, :attr3=>6}}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

<sup>1 The common key is represented by an underscore to signify that it is not used in the block calculation.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.